# How to get session information on xhtml jsf page from managedBean?

Tags: java, session, jsf, icefaces

I have following piece of code in my jsp file which `getSession` information:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="bookBean" class="beans.trade.BookBean" scope="session">
    <% bookBean.setSession( request.getSession() ); %>
 </jsp:useBean>
```

now I am trying to use `jsf` on the page and in my `managedBean` I am making call to `EJB` and getting their references. 
Here is the sample:

```
public void setSession(HttpSession session)
{
    super.setSession(session); 
    InitialContext ic = getInitialContext();
    booksLocalOps = ((BookOpsLocalHome) ic.lookup(BookOpsLocalHome.JNDI_NAME)).create();
    books = booksLocalOps.findBooksByOrg("ORG");
}
```

Now I have my `xhtml` page as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
      xmlns:p="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ice-cc="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces-composite-comps">
<h:head>
    <title>bookTemplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <ice:form>
        <p align="center">
            <ice:outputText value="Book Template" style="text-align:center;font-size:40px;"></ice:outputText>
        </p>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <p align="center">
            <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
                <ice:panelGrid>
                    <ice:outputText value="Book Name:" style="text-align:left;font-size:20px;"
                                    id="bookName"></ice:outputText>
                </ice:panelGrid>
                <ice:panelGrid>
                    <ice:inputText id="BookNameInputText" style="width: 195px;"
                                   value="#{bookBean.bookName}"></ice:inputText>
                </ice:panelGrid>
            </ice:panelGrid>
        </p>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </ice:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

So my question is how can i get `session` information on that page?

**Update**

I am debugging the application and when i try to get `initialContext` then I end up with `javax.servlet.ServletException: Session cannot be null` exception thrown, not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: Try referring [similar question on JSF sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282251/saving-data-to-session-in-jsf).

Comment: As suggested by BalusC, I used `FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);` and got HTTP session in my Bean and was able to get userDetails informations that are present in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html) for your startup.

But you can get your session with a java scriplet which will be against the ICEfaces conventions. so you don't need to access any session as long as you have access to all your bean data through your ICEfaces tags in the xhtml file.

Comment: can you elaborate more on how this would really work as am not able to understand much about it.